# Looking for an AR with image recognition library

Tags: android, ios, mobile, augmented-reality

I'm working on a project in which we have to launch several AR animations after detection of a toy's face. There are 36 toy's models and each toy must have a specific animation.

In other similar projects we have worked with common AR libraries but we never had to face the image recognition issue.

Do you know any library that could fit into that case?

After googling a lot I've found qualcomm Vuforia and it seems interesting. Have you used it or heard comments about it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Qualcomm is a really good library, completely up-to-date. We have worked with it and results are difficult to improve with other libraries. The problem is that it is not free.

If you want a free library where you can build your own SDK then OpenCV is the choice. You have all the functions you need. You will need to spend some time in understanding it and coding, but for your application it is quite easy.

Comment: Actually what we are trying now is to build a qualcomm-like SDK with OpenCV functions, and it is taking us some time.

Comment: In the following days I'll be examining both libraries and then I'll post here my impressions. Thank you all, guys, for your fast and useful comments.

My only worry is if they have the enough accuracy to differentiate the toy's faces (it has to be an animation asigned to each toy via facial recognition).

Comment: Yes they have. I can even tell you how to use the algorithms. If you use openCV you can use FAST detector for real time and SIFT detector for the pictures of the toys. Then, use a matcher to compare the points detected and you will get which toy is in the scene. It is kind of simple problem. A more difficult one is to find the coordinates 3D of the toy in the scene, but that's another task...

Comment: Thank you very much, Jav Rock, what you've told us it's exactly what we needed to know.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/).  Great open source library that is perfect for applications like this.

Comment: Would openCV allow you to differentiate between faces though?  I was under the impression that it simply allows you to identify that there is a face in the image, not who's (or what) it is.

Comment: [Google OpenCV object detection](https://www.google.com/search?q=opencv+object+recognition&sugexp=chrome,mod=6&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).  It is true that OpenCV does face detection, not face recognition.  But you are not dealing with either, as this applies only to human faces.  Since you are dealing with a comparatively small number of **toy** faces, OpenCV is a very viable option.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm going to test it now, for what you're saying it's possible to be what I'm looking for.

Comment: Don't expect this to necessarily work out of the box.  There is a bit of a learning curve.  But if your investigation reveals that this is the direction would will take, please accept this answer so others can better access the information.

Answer (score 1):

I've used Vuforia on a previous project.  It's very robust, but target size and tracking stability was an issue (small targets would sometimes not trigger, and models would jump around alot since our targets were narrow).  We used the Unity plugin, not the ios native since we didn't want to spend time writing openGL.

It's got a decent community on the qualcomm site, and it's price is right.  It doesn't offer some of the more advanced AR features yet (like pointcloud.io or others like that).